# Bootstrap - size of the col in relation of parent col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

EDIT: I solved my problem. Explanation at the bottom.

Sorry for my english but it is hard to explain :/
When basic column take "md-4" size and is too small, then input child should break line and become 100% width. But if basic column will change class to "sm-6" then become bigger and the input child should return inline.

How to resolve that problem?

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #fbb3b3">

        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="This input should break line, when is too small">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="But if is enough space it should stay inline">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #76ddf3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #fcfa96">
        Try to resize window and you will see what am I talking about.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

EDIT: Solition - I used javascript function, which detects the change of the width of the form and adds class col-xs to the elements or take it. So easy... Effect at the picture:
[image: SOLVED]

Comment: It's because you're using it wrong. I created a codepen and fixing this for you. Expect an answer in 10 minutes or less.

Comment: Answers didn't help me. I have done it differently.

Comment: I'm glad you was able to figure it out. Good debugging skills!

Answer (score 0):

hi can you try this one

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
          <div id="form1" class="panel-body">
           <form role="form"">

            <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-tag"  ></i></span>
             <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"  ></i></span>
             <input class="form-control" type="password" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 30%;">Login</button>
                        <hr>
                         <a href="forgot_password.php">Forgot Password?</a>
           </form>
          </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this: http://codepen.io/imcodingideas/pen/QdGwMp?editors=1000 but you can see what I tried here:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="background-color: #fbb3b3">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="background-color: #76ddf3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, inventore facere eius, corporis dicta reiciendis consequatur, consequuntur rem perferendis obcaecati maiores odit commodi officiis ratione accusamus necessitatibus.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="background-color: #fcfa96">
      <p>Try to resize window and you will see what am I talking about.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you're trying to do? Remember that p tags are block level elements.